# Uploading to S3, getting boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Consider this code

```
    file = request.files["wg_puid"]
    filename = hash + ".wargamerpl2"
    zipname = hash + ".zip"
    file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
    os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, mode='w').write(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
    else:
        return apology("Something went wrong", 400)


    # Uploads replay to S3
    # TODO fix error
    key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, zipname)
    with open(zipname, "rb") as f:
        key.send_file(f)
```

What I'm attempting to .zip a file that's uploaded to the server, and then send that file to my S3 bucket. I'm currently getting an error:

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>An error occurred when parsing the HTTP request.</Message><RequestId>3184ACA27BE403B1</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
```

What's wrong with my code here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `set_contents_from_filename` , not `send_file`

Here is my code, fixed and working.

```
        # Upload percentage
    def percent_cb(complete, total):
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    # Upload .zip to S3 bucket
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = zipname
    k.set_contents_from_filename(zipname, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```